# VB.Net String Replace Separated by Comma

Tags: vb.net

I have a string that contains numbers

`label1.text = 2,8,11,9,1,12`

Now when I replace 1 it replaces 11 too and I don't want that to happen

I would like when I remove something it just remove the specific thing
but 1 will also remove 11

I'm using this for a branchaccess for multiple branch the numbers are the ids of the branch

```
label1.text = 2,8,11,9,1,12

Dim newstring As String
newstring = Label1.Text.Replace("," & "1", "")
Label1.Text = newstring
```

Can anyone please help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that there are never spaces between your numbers, you could do something like:

```
label1.text = "2,8,11,9,1,12"

Dim newstring As String
newstring = label1.Text.Replace(",1,", ",")
If newstring.StartsWith("1,") Then
    newstring = newstring.Substring(2)
End If
If newstring.EndsWith(",1") Then
    newstring = newstring.Substring(0, newstring.Length - 2)
End If
label1.Text = newstring
```

This does three things:

1. Replace instances of `,1,` with `,` (removing 1 and one comma from the middle of the text)
2. Remove `1,` from the start of the string (*only if it is there*)
3. Remove `,1` from the end of the string (*only if it is there*)

You could also use a Regular Expression to achieve the same result, which may be cleaner or more efficient.

Comment: THANK YOU SO SO MUCH <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better way would be store the branch IDs separately and join them together only when you want to show them in the label.

For example,

```
Dim branchIds As New List(Of Integer) From {2, 8, 11, 9, 1, 12}
branchIds.Remove(1)

Label1.Text = String.Join(",", branchIds)
```

results in Label1 showing `2,8,11,9,12`.

That way, you could change the "," to, say,  ", " to improve readabilty, and it would make no difference to how the branch IDs are processed. It is a good idea to separate the data from the *display of* the data.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for This <3